# Trouble with Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems

Tags: mysql

I'm getting error 1045 when I try to log into my mysql root user. I am trying to follow the directions to reset my password on the mysql website https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html, but I'm having trouble with it.

the first step is this - 1. Log on to your system as the Unix user that the MySQL server runs as (for example, mysql).

I've just logged onto the administrator account onto my computer for this that I always use mysql for. then I ran the command `'mysql service stop;'`

the second step 2 - top the MySQL server if it is running. Locate the .pid file that contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common locations are /var/lib/mysql/, /var/run/mysqld/, and /usr/local/mysql/data/. Generally, the file name has an extension of .pid and begins with either mysqld or your system's host name.

I don't have the directory paths to /var/run/mysqld and /usr/local/mysql/data, but /var/lib/mysql shows this

```
cd var/lib/mysql
root@Roedelius:/var/lib/mysql# ls
auto.cnf         ibdata1      mysql               performance_schema
debian-5.7.flag  ib_logfile0  mysql_upgrade_info  posts
ib_buffer_pool   ib_logfile1  mytodo              sys
```

I have no .pid files here so I don't know how to continue onto the next steps. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Stopping my mysql service and doing this

```
orpheus@Roedelius:~$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

shows this

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2018-08-01T22:03:56.332143Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-08-01T22:03:56.332216Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Roedelius.lower-test
2018-08-01T22:03:56.332241Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 9399 ...
2018-08-01T22:03:56.334186Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Roedelius.lower-test
2018-08-01T22:03:56.334201Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Roedelius.lower-test
2018-08-01T22:03:56.334463Z 0 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

2018-08-01T22:03:56.334491Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /var/lib/mysql/
2018-08-01T22:03:56.334502Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-08-01T22:03:56.334514Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-08-01T22:03:56.334551Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'` give?

Comment: ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host 'localhost'

Comment: Wierd error.. Because your `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` shows a `root             | localhost` record... Your MySQL server looks suspect for some kind of corruption prime candidate for reinstallation or a new MySQL installation on a other port.. So you might be able to restore the data from one server into a other.

Comment: I don't think its corrupted since it was working fine until today when I logged into root. I haven't tried resetting my root password with --skip-grant-tables yet and I'm still now sure how to start mysql with --skip-grant-tables. If you know how please tell me.

Comment: `mysql --skip-grant-tables` can't work because mysql is the client program.. You need use `--skip-grant-tables` on the server program called `mysqld`.. manual is explaining https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I've been looking at that but I can't find the .pid file in step 2 for the unix directions on it. I've updated my whole answer to be about this now.

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to days to look for the plugin definition:

```
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

If user root uses auth_socket, then only a process running as root will be able to connect as root, regardless of the password.

It also says if you want to use password authentication for root, you should use this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

**Edit:**
To use `--skip-grant-tables`, stop your mysql server, then start it manually with

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: that shows this `SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | localhost |                       |`.   if I use that update mysql.user command, where it says plugin='mysql_native_password', do I type in any new password that I want to set it to? I set the password before to 'woofwoof' with the commands shown in my answer above but I still got error 1045.

Comment: The empty column plugin seems to indicate that the mysql server doesn't use plugins. On the other hand, the column is present, which would indicate that it should be supported.

Comment: I tried doing that to use --skip-grant-tables and got a big error that is in my question above now. Have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You must run mysqld as root (or use sudo)

Comment: I typed these commands in `orpheus@Roedelius:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
[sudo] password for orpheus: ` and then it showed nothing on my terminal lines, so I think it worked. Then I started the mysql service again and logged in with another user and  did this `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'woofwoof';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
`  It's not running the same steps as the unix reset password guide on mysql's site. What am I doing wrong here?